# Storing API keys and secrets in database

Tags: html, node.js, heroku, db2, cloudinary

I am integrating Cloudinary in my nodejs dashboard, which will allow customers to upload images to the app. However, I want this to be as automated as possible, but I know you need api keys and api secret keys to connect to cloudinary server. It it good practice to store each clients api keys in my db2 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use an .env file. For example here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage

Alternatively, you can use [the unsigned upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload). using the node sdk or the [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget).